# Sending deauthentication packets on android using android pcap source code

Tags: java, android, wifi, aircrack-ng, packet-injection

I am looking for confirmation on if what I want to do is even possible, and any suggestions on how to approach what I want to do. I am wanting to create a wifi jamming device to show people how their wifi devices are vulnerable to jamming simply by sending deauthentication packets. This would be with their consent. I am wanting to do this on android so I can take it with me to show my friends. I have looked around, and I now own the necessary OTG cable and an alfa AWUS036H usb adapter. My issue is now with how to get it to interact with the android device correctly (which is an android galaxy s3 or s5, I have both available for tinkering with, although if I am going to run risks on one I would prefer the s3.) I have found some wonderful source code that has accomplished packet sniffing with the Rtl8187 chipset that the AWUS036H has, but it does not support packet injection. Here is the page containing the java code for it: http://kismetwireless.net/gitweb/?p=android-pcap.git;a=tree;f=src/net/kismetwireless/android/pcapcapture;h=c50d93ed3cf9ab2bd0b1ae84145fec68686979bd;hb=HEAD
I am wondering if there is a way to modify it to send deauthentication packets similar to aircrack-ng. I am aware of the android kernel modifying method running kali on the device and porting drivers in, but I wanted to try this first. This is considering the difficulty level of modifying an android kernel.
P.S. I have considered buying a raspberry pi and loading kali linux for this purpose, I just don't currently want to spend the money on the pi and a battery. Thank you for your time.

Edit: Here is the application for android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kismetwireless.android.pcapcapture&hl=en